# When should I put the adjective before the noun?

Tags: orden-de-palabras

In a recent spanish reading, I came across this:

"un monstruo loco." (a crazy monster)

In other readings, I always see the adjective before the noun. Was this a mistake? If possible, please explain when I should / should not put the adjective before the noun.

Comment: This may be of help: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15636/placement-of-adjectives-in-spanish/15637#15637

Comment: Thank you Gustavson.

Comment: Or this one: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/what-is-the-difference-among-una-persona-buena-una-buena-persona-and-es-bu/18679#18679

Answer (score 2):

This website has plenty of good examples: https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/adjective-placement

This is just one important example to remember:

> 2. Limiting Adjectives
>
> Limiting adjectives that define a number or amount of a noun, even if it is not specific, come before the noun.
>
> Check out these examples of limiting adjectives.
>
> examples

> Los niños quieren ocho helados. The children want eight ice creams.

> Tengo menos dinero que mi hermana. I have less money than my sister.

> Hay pocas naranjas este verano. There are few oranges this summer.

> Tienes suficiente tiempo. You have sufficient time.

Check out more examples, including the one above, here: https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/adjective-placement