# Yo soy un simple soldado - corrido and why the adjective-noun order is like in english?

Tags: adjetivos, orden-de-palabras

My Spanish is bad I remember briefly watching some youtube video where a mexican was singing a corrido in Spain and said something like "yo soy un simple soldado".

Why is the adjective in front of soldado? Should it be "soldado simple"?

Comment: Please capitalize languages in English and please fix your sentence. Also, look up the word in the Diccionario de la Real Academia (in other words, please do research before posting. Also, questions in English go like this: Why **is** the adjective in front of soldado. Should it be X?

Comment: @Lambie: no todo el mundo domina el inglés como Vd. Dele cuartelillo al OP

Comment: @Ananias Creo que la persona sabe bastante inglés. Se ve por la pregunta completa que sabe bastante.

Comment: @Lambie: Puede que tenga Vd toda la razón del mundo y parte de la del otro pero, in dubio, pro reo.

Comment: @Lambie Por qué no colaborás con el sitio y editás vos la pregunta en lugar de ponerte a criticar? No te parece más fácil? A lo sumo, además de editar, dejale un comentario y ya; tampoco es el fin del mundo porque no sepa escribir inglés

Comment: @tac Porque asi la persona no aprende nada. No es el inglés el más importante: el la falta de búsqueda.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I put the adjective before the noun?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/37757/when-should-i-put-the-adjective-before-the-noun)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spanish is a very flexible language. Though the normal use is "noun + adjective" we usually reverse the order. In the example you gave "yo soy un simple soldado" the adjective meaning is stressed by putting it first (I am just a soldier). If it were "Yo soy un soldado simple" the meaning would be slightly different (something like "I am a modest soldier").

Comment: Está bien encarada la respuesta. Pero deberías completarla hablando acerca de la diferencia de los adjetivos **relacionales** y los adjetivos **calificativos**. Los primeros van sí o sí pospuestos y esto es lo que le va a traer problemas y confusiones al OP

Answer (score 3):

In Spanish, sometimes we place the adjective before the noun (antepuesto) or after it (pospuesto). Sometimes it can change the meaning completely:

Una pobre viuda (a poor widow, I pity her but she could be rich or poor) //
Una viuda pobre (a poor widow, she's got no money)

In your example, it would be:
Un simple soldado (he's just a soldier and nothing more. He's not a general)
// Un soldado simple (he's a plain soldier, not a sophisticated, not elegant etc)

In general, but not always, an adjective after the noun gives an objective meaning, whereas an adjective before the noun is subjective and gives a subjective meaning:

Alta cuna (high-born)
// Cuna alta (a crib that is visibly high or tall)

I hope this helps.